# How to use matlab's filter function to compute samples of the impulse response of a filter?

Tags: matlab, filter, sample

I have the following code so far:

```
[b,a] = ellip(4,.2,40,[.41 .47]); //elliptical filter
[H,w] = freqz(b,a,4096);
```

I need to figure out how to compute 4096 samples of the impulse response of the filter. I can't figure out how. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `b` and `a`, so you can `filter` an impulse to get the impulse response:

```
imp = [1, zeros(1, 4095)]
h = filter(b, a, imp);
```

For your example, `plot(h)` should yield something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[h,t] = impz(b,a, 4096)
```

Use [impz() function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/impz.html), h is the data and t is the sample number.